# Binary trees in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

How would I count how many nodes a tree has?

```
;;; A Binary is one of:
;;; - Number
;;; - (make-node BT BT)


(define-struct node (left right))

(define tree1 (make-node (make-node 10 9)
(make-node 3
(make-node 1 5))))

(define (how-many? nd)
  (cond
    [(number? nd)....]
    [(node? n)
     (..... (how-many? (node-left nd))
             (how-many? (node-right nd)))]))
```

so for tree1 I should get

```
 (check-expect (how-many? tree1) 5)
```

I think I got the template right. If it's a number, you should return `1`. But if it's a `node`, what type of function should I put in the dotted lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is somewhat similar to how you'd process a list. The difference? that now you'll go to the "left" and to the "right" of each node, instead of going just to the "rest". Other than that, the same ideas apply:

```
(define (how-many? nd)
  (cond
    [(number? nd) <???>] ; if it's a leaf, then how many numbers does it have?
    [(node? nd)
     (<???> (how-many? (node-left nd)) ; how do we combine the results?
            (how-many? (node-right nd)))]))
```

You got the base case right, as I can see in the question. The recursive case is simple! remember, how did we *combine* the results when we were *adding* the elements in a list? here's the same thing, it's just that we combine the results from the left and from the right subtrees.

Comment: So just the addition sign? How in the world. Wouldn't you use the addition sign if you wanted to add all the nodes together? wow!

Comment: @Josh it's the magic of recursion: every time you call `how-many?`, you're getting the number of nodes in that part of the tree - be it left or right. To obtain the sum of the whole tree, just add the result from the left plus the result from the right

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thanks.

Comment: @Josh Always ask yourself the question: how can I _combine_ the results? the result of the first element and the rest of elements (in the case of lists). Or the result of the current node, the left subtree and the right subtree (in the case of trees). In this particular tree is even simpler, because only the leafs of the tree contain data