# Representing tree as a list

Tags: scheme, racket

I should write a function which calculates amount of leaves in the given tree. Before writing algorithm, I want to be sure about my representation.

[image: my tree]

For this tree, my representation is:

```
(define liste 
    (list '5 (list '1 (list '8) (list '2 (list '1) (list '9))) (list '10) 
    (list '4 (list '9))))
```

Is that correct?

My other question is that do I need any parameter except list for this function?

Btw, I know that I don't need to write `list` every time but this looks more clear for me.

**Edit:**

```
(define (howmany L)
    (if (empty? L) 
        0
        (if (= (length L) 1)
            (+ 1 (howmany (cdr L)))
            (if (= (length (car (cdr L))) 1)
                (+ 1 (howmany (cdr L)))
                (howmany (cdr L))))))
```

When I call `(howmany (list-ref liste 1))`, it returns 2. However, it should return 3. *(8, 1, 9)*

When I call `(howmany (list-ref liste 2))`, it retursn 1. Fine.

When I call `(howmany (list-ref liste 3))`, it returns 2. It should return 1. (*Only 9)*

What's my mistake?

Comment: Looks good to me. By the way, numbers are self-evaluating and do not need to be quoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indenting the expression to mimick the graphical representation of the tree reveals that your expression is correct:

```
(define liste 
  (list 5 
        (list 1 
              (list 8) 
              (list 2 
                    (list 1) 
                    (list 9)))
        (list 10) 
        (list 4 
              (list 9))))
```

A shorter way to a structural equivalent value is:

```
      '(5
        (1
         (8)
         (2
          (1)
          (9)))
        (10)
        (4
         (9)))
```

Your `sum-of-leaves` function does not need more parameters, but if you want to use an accumulator, you can write:

```
(define (sum tree)
  (sum-it tree 0))

(define (sum-it tree sum-so-far)
   ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I edited my post, have some counting problems. Hope you can help.

Comment: Maybe you can get inspired by:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986977/binary-trees-in-scheme

Answer (score 3):

To count up your leaves.

```
(define (node-count-of-leaves node)
  (let ((count 0))
    (node-walk (lambda (node)
                 (when (node-is-leaf? node)
                   (set! count (+ 1 count)))
               node)
    count))
```

As regards your `how many` function, you are not recursing down the tree correctly and perhaps adding 1 on non-leaves.

For the above code, abstraction is your friend:

```
(define (make-node value . children)
  `(,value ,@children))

(define node-value car)
(define node-children cdr)

(define (make-leaf-node value)
   (make-node value))
(define (node-is-leaf? node)
  (null? (node-children node)))

(define (node-degree node)
  (length (node-children node)))
```

Now you get to use descriptively-named functions, like `node-children`, rather then, in your representation, combinations of `car`, `cdr`, `cadr`, etc.

With the above, go ahead and build a tree.

```
(define my-tree
  (make-node 5
    (make-node 1 ...)
    (make-leaf-node 10)
    (make-node 4 ...)))
```

and then you can walk the tree:

```
(define (node-walk func node)
  (func node)
  (for-each (lambda (node) (node-walk func node))
            (node-children node))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @GoZoner, but I think I can't use your method because this is an assignment and if I use your method, I'm sure that my professor will comment like I cheated.

Comment: Must be better ways to traverse a tree than with `for-each` which leads you to side effects. `accumulate-tree` from SICP, which is like `fold`, but for trees perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my implementation of the `count-leaves` function:

```
(define (count-leaves tree)
  (if (null? (cdr tree))
      1
      (let loop ((count 0)
                 (children (cdr tree)))
        (if (null? children)
            count
            (loop (+ count (count-leaves (car children)))
                  (cdr children))))))
```

Or, if you're allowed to use `map` in your assignment, it can be much shorter:

```
(define (count-leaves tree)
  (if (null? (cdr tree))
      1
      (apply + (map count-leaves (cdr tree)))))
```

Tests (tested under Racket):

```
> (count-leaves tree)
5
> (count-leaves (second tree))
3
> (count-leaves (third tree))
1
> (count-leaves (fourth tree))
1
```